# How to run SQLite3 'PRAGMA' commands via C-API?

Tags: sql, c, database, sqlite

Inside my C-program, I need to run the following pragma command:

```
  const char *sql = "PRAGMA table_info(family)"; /* 'family' is the table name */
```

But whether i try to run this sql via `sqlite3_exec()` routine or `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` routine, my program stops responding/working at Windows command-prompt (it's a simple 'console program' in c-language).

Interestingly, when i run that same pragma sql at command-prompt normally by running the sqlite3.exe itself, it runs just fine and gives following output:

```
    sqlite> pragma table_info(family);
cid         name        type        notnull     dflt_value  pk
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           id          INTEGER     0                       1
1           name        TEXT        1                       0
2           nickname    TEXT        1                       0
3           dob         TEXT        1           CURRENT_TI  0
```

But inside my own c-program it doesn't. I have done a bit research about this problem. Both Googling and SQLite Documentation point towards [this page here](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) at the official docs. But unfortunately the given information there hasn't enabled me enough to resolve the problem. How can we successfully run SQLite3 'PRAGMA' commands via C-API?

**EDIT: Here are the actual problematic lines of code. OR [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

I have found the reasons of my program's failure, and have fixed it (Courtesy of clues and leads in [Murphy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711640/how-to-run-sqlite3-pragma-commands-via-c-api/46711932#46711932). But for those interested in reproducing the problem, here are the actual lines of code which were causing program to "crash".
Inside my callback function for `sqlite3_exec()` routine, I had this piece of code(for-loop) for printing ' ---------- ' characters below column names to mimic "`.mode column`" & "`.headers on`" style of output in sqlite3 console.

```
      int h;    
      for(h=0; h <= (strlen(col_value[i])+5); h++)
          printf("-");
```

The problem was being caused by `strlen()` while printing '`headers`' for PRAGMA sql's result column `dflt_value` which is null for first three columns in my table. If i stop running `strlen()` on `dflt_value`. the program runs fine. Similarly, in `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` routine the problem was being caused by the following lines:

```
      int h;    
      for(h=0; h <= (strlen(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4))+5); h++)
          printf("-");
```

If i remove or comment these lines, all runs well - albeit without "`.headers on`" style.

Comment: ".mode column" & ".headers on" style? What's that?

Comment: @John When the official compiled SQLite application, sqlite3.exe, is run, standalone, in Console (Command Line Shell), there ".mode column" command outputs "select" query result set in formatted columns style, and ".headers on" command puts column headers on top of result-set table columns. You may further research via their official docs at https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlite3_exec()` should indeed be the way to go to execute pragma commands. You didn't give a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (shame on you!), but I suspect that you either neglect handling error values, or something else is wrong with your code. You should try debugging it.

Comment: Thank you for the clues and leads. I have provided MCVE, And to whom it may concern: sqlite3_exec() and sqlite3_prepare_v2(), both routines work. :)